# Get File Size of stored files and new uploaded ones

Tags: java, mysql

I have a web app that is connected to a mySQL DB in BLOB Format, and there are some files stored in the DB, how can I fetch their sizes and add them to a new column in the table I'm using ? And what is the best approach to get file size of an uploaded file in JAVA ?!

Comment: How do you get new uploaded files ? You can use `File.length()`.

Comment: And what is your MySQL data type ? If `BLOB`, then use `OCTET_LENGTH(your_column_name)` statement (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648809/calculating-total-data-size-of-blob-column-in-a-table).

Comment: Yes it is BLOB... Will try that method thank you

Comment: @Gaël Does it matter if it was BLOB or not?

Comment: File size is in Bits correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your new records that will be processed in Java you can use `File.length()` if you're working with a `File` object.

And for existing records, you can use `OCTET_LENGTH(your_column_name)` statement (source: [Calculating total data size of BLOB column in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648809/calculating-total-data-size-of-blob-column-in-a-table)) which will give you the size in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

select file_name, Octet_length(blob_colume) as "Size in Bytes" from Table_name;